# Android Resourcse linking Failed while using : buildFeatures {viewBinding = true}

Tags: android, gradle, aapt, android-viewbinding

After starting an android studio today, I came across a strange problem. It was saying

> **DSL element 'android.viewBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been**
>   **replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.viewBinding'.**

After searching for a bit I found out that I had to use

> **buildFeatures {viewBinding = true}**

instead. So, I replaced **viewBinding{enabled=true}** with the above one. After that, the real problems started. AAPT can no longer detect my drawables. Here is my buildScript:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.techtrixbd.RestaurantApp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {viewBinding = true}
}
```

I don't know what is going on anymore. Any advice will be a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I had to move my resources to drawable-v24 folder. that's it. But, don't why it was required because everything was working fine yesterday. Maybe an update has something to do with it. I will look for the cause and will post if I come up with something.

Comment: Can you give more details on your solution ? I have tried to add  the buildfeatures in android but I still have the warning... I cannot find a solution (I have tried lot of different syntaxes but nothing is working). Thanks

Comment: OK solved, I had just to remove this old line : viewBinding.enabled = true, and I replaced it with : android.buildFeatures.viewBinding = true

Comment: Nice to hear. Happy coding